# A question from calculus 2 course - Maclaurin theorem with remainder

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Thank you in advance.
For $x > -1, x\neq 0$ prove that:
If $\alpha>1$ or $\alpha<0$ then $(1+x)^{\alpha} > 1 + \alpha x$ ;
And if $0<\alpha<1$ then $(1+x)^{\alpha} < 1 + \alpha x$

I've found that the Maclaurin theorem (first order) for $(1+x)^\alpha$ is
$$(1+x)^\alpha = \sum _{k=0}^{1}\binom{\alpha}{k}x^k+R_1(x)=\binom{\alpha}{0}x^0+\binom{\alpha}{1}x^1+R_1(x)=1+\alpha x+R_1(x)$$
but I'm not sure about the remainder (Lagrange form) and how to deal with it.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the explicit forms for the remainder; show that the remainder is positive for $\alpha\gt1,\alpha\lt0$, and that the remainder is negative for $0\lt\alpha\lt1$.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm currently trying. I just need to make sure that $\binom{\alpha}{2}\xi^2$ when $-1<\xi<0$ or $0<\xi<x$ is the actual remainder, and I'm not mistaken. From there I think I got it.

Comment: You can be sure

Comment: Thank you! You've helped me! Have an awesome day!

Comment: More specifically, $\binom{\alpha}{2}(1+\xi)^{\alpha-2}\cdot x^2$ is the remainder... but it’s the same ideas. You’re welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prove for first case, second follows suit. Remainder after n terms$$ \frac{x^n e^{åx}}{n!} $$.
After two terms, $$ \frac{x^2 e^{åx}}{2!} > 0 $$, since all components are positive hence result follows